# How change the value of the form element by each second?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have class that extends ProgressBar which should release a simple timer.

```
    public partial class TimerBar: ProgressBar
    {
        public TimerBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Value = 100; 
        }
        ...
        public void Start()
        {
            int x = 100/Timer; // procent per second

            for (i = Value; i > 0; i--) {
               Value -= x;
            }
        }
     }
```

How to set delay for 1 second before `Value -= x` ?
(It should not stop other elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the windorms [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class to raise an event to call a method every second from within your class. This does not block the thread. You would have to re-write your logic a bit and not use a for loop, but it should be able to provide what you need.

Comment: To expand a bit:  the `Timer` class provides a `Tick` event.  You set the timer for 1 second intervals, and on each `Tick`, update your UI.  Beware of the need to [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx) if threading gets involved, as others are suggesting.

Comment: @DonBoitnott note that you are comment is about *different* timer class - WinForms's one *does not* need `Invoke` as it runs on UI thread.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ..."if threading gets involved".  I think I covered that.

Comment: @DonBoitnott That quote is a very far cry from the actual situation, which is, "if you use the wrong timer".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep loop in the code (and hence can't use `Timer` approach suggested in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32742727/477420) ) you can use async/await with `Task.Delay`:

```
public async void Start()
{
    int x = 100/Timer; // percent per second

    for (i = Value; i > 0; i--) {
       Value -= x;
       await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't await block the thread Start() is called on, blocking the UI thread?

Comment: @LexWebb No, it would not.

Comment: FYI: async/await keywords available only from .net 4.5 and up.